# Will Linux select the fastest CPU in a SMP system

Tags: linux, performance, scheduling

In a system with for example two physical CPU's, four cores per CPU. If one physical CPU is slower (lower clockspeed, other model) will the Linux process scheduler be smart enough to migrate a high demand process to the fastest core?

If it is, how is load average calculated on a system with one slow and one fast CPU physical CPU?

Comment: What system do you have with multiple CPUs that aren't all the same speed?

Comment: I've *never* seen any system with CPUs that weren't exactly matched (down to stepping).

Comment: By definition of Symmetric Multiprocessor System that would be impossible as it would not be symmetric anymore if equipped with several different kinds of processors. So the answer is no because the question is inherently contradictory.

Comment: I administrate a Lenovo RD220 server at work. I have not seen anything in the documentation requiring a secondary CPU to be of the same clockspeed as the primary. I may be wrong on this tough.
Regardless I cant see how this is relevant to the essence of the question.